# Web scrape return empty values

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to scoop the new inventory on this truck sales site, but can't seem to get the problem.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://usedtrucks.ryder.com/en/search-used-trucks#/facet-search?g=tractor&r=united-states&group=tandem-axle-sleeper&price=22563&price=30741&f=new-inventory&trant=auto&trant=auto-shift&sleeper=condo&sort=11&view=list","table",1)
```

I have tried table number up to 35. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image: 0]

Comment: 99% sure it's not possible.